# How to use OR operator in Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have two different type of OS, which return the `service tomcat status` output differently.

I have a method to get the tomcat process ID.

```
def find_pid(pattern,status):
    m = re.match(pattern, status, re.DOTALL)
    pid = m.groups(0)[0]
    return(pid)
print(find_pid(pattern,status))
```

OS type1 `service tomcat status`  returns

```
status = 'jsvc (pid  2164) is running...'
```

Pattern used to get PID

```
pattern = '.*pid\s+(\d+).*running.*'
print(find_pid(pattern,status))           >>> 2164
```

OS type2 `service tomcat status` returns

```
status = '''tomcat.service - Tomcat Server
   Loaded: loaded ( enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-18 13:33:00 PST; 1min 47s ago
 Main PID: 2800 (jsvc)
   CGroup: /system/tomcat.service
'''
```

Pattern used to get PID

```
pattern = '.*PID:\s+(\d+).*'
print(find_pid(pattern,status))          >>> 2800
```

Now I don't want to check the type of OS and I dont want to send different pattern for different OS.

The pattern should be able to get the PID irrespective of which type of OS we are checking,

I created a method by combining above two patterns with a '|' operator.

```
def find_pid(status):
    pattern = '.*pid\s+(\d+).*running.*|.*PID:\s+(\d+).*'
    m = re.match(pattern, status, re.DOTALL)
    pid = m.groups(0)[0]
    return(pid)
print(find_pid(status))
```

This method is not working for either of the status.

I need a pattern which would match both type of status and return me the PID from it.

PS: If possible, I need the solution which would work both in python 2 and 3.  Because Few test vms run in python2 and few run in python3 environment. (working on porting 2 to 3).

Comment: How about using if-else, i.e. first check if there is a match with the first pattern and if no match, try the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a case insensitive match, flag `re.I`, `:?` since not both strings have a `:` before the PID and `(\d{1,5})` to group the digits (max of 5, assumed os-limits).

```
import re

os1_status = 'jsvc (pid  2164) is running...'
os2_status = '''tomcat.service - Tomcat Server
   Loaded: loaded ( enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-18 13:33:00 PST; 1min 47s ago
 Main PID: 2800 (jsvc)
   CGroup: /system/tomcat.service
'''

for status in (os1_status, os2_status):
    match = re.search(r'pid:?\s+(\d{1,5})', status, re.I)
    print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking in account test cases:

```
jsvc (pid  2164) is running...
```

and

```
tomcat.service - Tomcat Server
   Loaded: loaded ( enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-18 13:33:00 PST; 1min 47s ago
 Main PID: 2800 (jsvc)
   CGroup: /system/tomcat.service
```

I suggest using following universal pattern

```
r".*[Pp][Ii][Dd]:?\s+(\d+)"
```

Note that I used `[Pp][Ii][Dd]` to accept any case without need to use flags, if you are in control of flags you might use `re.IGNORECASE` instead, e.g.

```
import re
test1 = '''jsvc (pid  2164) is running...'''
test2 = '''tomcat.service - Tomcat Server
   Loaded: loaded ( enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-18 13:33:00 PST; 1min 47s ago
 Main PID: 2800 (jsvc)
   CGroup: /system/tomcat.service'''
print(re.search(r".*pid:?\s+(\d+)", test1, re.IGNORECASE).group(1))
print(re.search(r".*pid:?\s+(\d+)", test2, re.IGNORECASE).group(1))
```

output

```
2164
2800
```